# Drupal 5 and node?destination=node

Tags: drupal, drupal-5

I've had a drupal 5 site for over 2 years. For some reason my browser dropdown URL retains `www.xxx.co.uk/node?destination=node` for the site url. This has work until now - when I get

The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

```
*   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
      cookies.
```

typing in the bare url `www.xxx.co.uk` gives the same results. I'd just modified the site to add another picture gallery. I can access the site by typing in `www.xxx.co.uk/node/1` but if I logout I'm back to the above problem, I assume for the same `destination=node` problem.

Didn't change any modules that I recall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I can answer this myself after a bit of investigation. I used import images to load my pics. What I failed to notice was that the nodes created by the import were all set to promoted to front page. Remove this from all the image nodes and everything is back to normal. No idea why my browser dropdown retains the url as above.